# I'm trying to make a list out of components attached to GameObjects with a certain tag, but I'm getting a NullReferenceException in the unity console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I rewrote this in various ways, but nothing up to now would do the trick. I made sure that everything is tagged correctly and has the right scripts attached as you can see in the pic. 
This is the stripped code of the class (CrowdControl) that is supposed to:

- find all objects tagged "Fighter"
- fill a list with all FighterControl scripts attached to them

```
    private List<FighterControl> fightersScripts;
   

    private void Start()
    {
        InitializeFighters();
    }

    private void InitializeFighters() // first line that the NullReferenceException is pointing at !!!!
    {
        GameObject[] tempfightersGM = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Fighter");
        for (int i = 0; i < tempfightersGM.Length; i++)
        {
            fightersScripts.Add( tempfightersGM[i].GetComponent<FighterControl>()); // second line that the NullReferenceException is pointing at !!!!
        }
    }
```

[Pic of the editor including the inspector view of the 2 game objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/198IQ.png)

Comment: Is `GameObject` null?

Comment: @DavidG `GameObject` is a type ... `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` is a `static` method  ;)

Comment: @Abenfante your list `fightersScripts` is not initialized! You should already declare it as `private readonly List<FighterControl> fightersScripts = new List<FighterControl>();`

Comment: Btw alternatively you could probably simply use `fighterScripts = FindObjectsOfType<FighterControl>().ToList();` (or use an array and skip the `ToList`)